# How to find frequency of numbers in a list from user input HTML

Tags: javascript, html, list, user-input, frequency

I'm trying to make a code that will give the sum, average, min, max, and frequency of numbers in a list. With the help of others, I was able to get the sum, average, max, and min, but not frequency. Im trying to make it so that when you click on a button that is next to the other math function buttons, it alerts you with how many times all of the numbers have shown up in the list. For example, if the list of numbers the user types in is 1,7,7,7,3,1, and the user clicks on the frequency button it outputs how many times 1 is in the list (2), how many times 7 is in the list (3), and how many times 3 is in the list (1).

```css
 .title { font-weight:bold; margin-top:1em; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>
   <head>

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

     </head>


   <body>

       <!--- This only allows the user to input numbers --->

     <input type='number' id='input'>

     <!--- This is the button that adds the number to the list --->

     <input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' disabled="disabled">

     <!--- Here we have a title for the list --->

     <div class="title">Topics</div>

     <!--- This will list all of the numbers --->

     <ul id='list'></ul> 

      <!--- When clicked, this buttons alert the user with the numbers --->

     <button id="sum"> Sum </button>
     <button id="max"> Max </button>
     <button id="min"> Min </button>
     <button id="avg"> Avg </button>


     <div>

       <button value="Refresh Page" onclick="window.location.reload()" > Reset! </button>

     </div>

     <script>

       let list = document.getElementById("list");
   let input = document.getElementById("input");
   let add = document.getElementById("add");
   var avg = 0;
   var sum = 0;
   var min = -Infinity;
   var max = Infinity;

   // This will add the input number to the list and clear the input

   function addClick () {
     var li = document.createElement("li");
     li.textContent = input.value;
     list.appendChild(li);
     update();
     input.value = "";  
     add.disabled = "disabled";
   } 

   // This allows the "add to list" button to be turned on/off depending if the user has typed in a number

   function enableDisable(){
     if(this.value === ""){
       add.disabled = "disabled";
     } else {
       add.removeAttribute("disabled");
     }
   }

   // This will calculate and update all variable values

   function update() {
     sum = 0;
     min = Infinity;
     max = -Infinity;
     var count = 0;
     for (var i of list.children) {
       let val = +i.textContent;
       sum += val;
       if (val > max) max = val;
       if (val < min) min = val;
       count++;
     }
     avg = sum/count;
   } 

   // This functions will alert the numbers

   function sumClick() {
     alert("The sum of your numbers is: " + sum);
   }
   function avgClick() {
     alert("The average of your numbers is: " + avg);
   }
   function minClick() {
     alert("The smaller number is: " + min);
   }
   function maxClick() {
     alert("The greater number is: " + max);
   } 

   // Here we add all events

   input.addEventListener("input", enableDisable);
   add.addEventListener("click", addClick);
   document.getElementById("avg").addEventListener("click", avgClick);
   document.getElementById("sum").addEventListener("click", sumClick); 
   document.getElementById("min").addEventListener("click", minClick); 
   document.getElementById("max").addEventListener("click", maxClick);


     </script>   


   </body>




   </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is keeping the frequency/counter in an object where the keys are the entered numbers.

```js
let list = document.getElementById("list");
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let add = document.getElementById("add");
var avg = 0;
var sum = 0;
var min = -Infinity;
var max = Infinity;
let frequency = Object.create(null);

// This will add the input number to the list and clear the input

function addClick() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = input.value;
  list.appendChild(li);
  update(input.value);
  input.value = "";
  add.disabled = "disabled";
 
}

// This allows the "add to list" button to be turned on/off depending if the user has typed in a number

function enableDisable() {
  if (this.value === "") {
    add.disabled = "disabled";
  } else {
    add.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}

// This will calculate and update all variable values

function update(enteredValue) {
  frequency[enteredValue] = (frequency[enteredValue] || 0) + 1;
  sum = 0;
  min = Infinity;
  max = -Infinity;
  var count = 0;
  for (var i of list.children) {
    let val = +i.textContent;
    sum += val;
    if (val > max) max = val;
    if (val < min) min = val;
    count++;
  }
  avg = sum / count;
}

function frequencyClick() {
  let text = Object.entries(frequency).reduce((a, [number, fqy]) => {
    return a.concat(`The number ${number} appeared ${fqy} time(s) in the list`)
  }, []).join('\n');
  
  alert(text);
}

// This functions will alert the numbers

function sumClick() {
  alert("The sum of your numbers is: " + sum);
}

function avgClick() {
  alert("The average of your numbers is: " + avg);
}

function minClick() {
  alert("The smaller number is: " + min);
}

function maxClick() {
  alert("The greater number is: " + max);
}

// Here we add all events

input.addEventListener("input", enableDisable);
add.addEventListener("click", addClick);
document.getElementById("avg").addEventListener("click", avgClick);
document.getElementById("sum").addEventListener("click", sumClick);
document.getElementById("min").addEventListener("click", minClick);
document.getElementById("max").addEventListener("click", maxClick);
document.getElementById("frequency").addEventListener("click", frequencyClick);
```

```css
.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!--- This only allows the user to input numbers --->

<input type='number' id='input'>

<!--- This is the button that adds the number to the list --->

<input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' disabled="disabled">

<!--- Here we have a title for the list --->

<div class="title">Topics</div>

<!--- This will list all of the numbers --->

<ul id='list'></ul>

<!--- When clicked, this buttons alert the user with the numbers --->

<button id="sum"> Sum </button>
<button id="max"> Max </button>
<button id="min"> Min </button>
<button id="avg"> Avg </button>
<button id="frequency"> Frequency </button>


<div>

  <button value="Refresh Page" onclick="window.location.reload()"> Reset! </button>

</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to add text inside the alert? For example it could say, "The number 1 appeared 3 times in the list" if the user typed in the number 1 three times.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a map that you update with the frequency of each number then output the results.

```
function calcFreq() {
  return list.children.map(i => +i.textContent).reduce((acc, val) => {
    if (acc[val]) {
      acc[val] += 1;
    } else {
      acc[val] = 1;
    }

    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```